# How create correct template file for ansible role

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need create some configuration file in yml wtith ansible role. This example what i want:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/system.log
    - /var/log/wifi.log
```

In ansible dirctory structue in Templates dir i have file with such text:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: {{filebeat_input.type}}
  {{ filebeat_input.paths | to_yaml}}
```

In Directory defaults i have such main.yml:
filebeat_create_config: true

```
filebeat_input:
    type: log
    paths:
     - "/var/log/*.log"
     - "/var/somelog/*.log"
```

When i`m run ansible-playbook with this role i`m got this:

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
  [/var/log/*.log, /var/sdfsadf]
```

Where i`m wrong ? what and where i need change to get exactly what i whant (see example above). 
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filebeat_input.paths` is a list, so when you pass it to `to_yaml` you get a list. You just need to structure your YAML template so that you're putting the list in the right place, e.g:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: {{filebeat_input.type}}
  paths: {{ filebeat_input.paths | to_yaml}}
```

Note that:

```
paths: [/var/log/*.log, /var/sdfsadf]
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
paths:
  - /var/log/*.log
  - /var/sdfsadf
```

Comment: thanks for answer ! so that all work as need. thanks again !